# Delve not creating __debug_bin file

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, delve

I'm a little stuck... I'm trying to get Delve to run in my docker container but it keeps exiting with the same error:

```
could not launch process: fork/exec /my/project/__debug_bin: function not implemented
```

When I've used Delve in other projects this `__debug_bin` file was created automatically by Delve and then removed after the debugging finished. But here it looks like it's not creating it?

Anyone know why or what I can do to debug this debugger further and find out the cause?

Here's the relevant part of my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

Dockerfile Delve installation

```
RUN go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv

RUN go mod vendor

RUN go install -gcflags="all=-N -l" -ldflags "-X main.version=$BUILD_VERSION" ./cmd/billing
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    billing:
        image: my/image
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
        volumes:
            - .:/my/project/path
        ports:
            - "${DEV_ENV_HOST:-0.0.0.0}:9800:9800" # main app port
            - "${DEV_ENV_HOST:-0.0.0.0}:40000:40000" # debugger port
```

And here's my delve command:

```
dlv debug --headless --listen=:40000 --api-version=2 --accept-multiclient --check-go-version=false ./cmd/billing
```

I can't think of what else to try to get this to work...

Answer (score 0):

The platforms of the host system and the docker image are not mentioned in the question, but this is most likely due to running an amd64 container on an arm64 host (<del>[delve#2910](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2910)</del>).

The reported issue was closed because it's considered as a duplicate of <del>[docker/for-mac#5191](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5191)</del>. This issue was closed because "The container is running in qemu (because amd64 is not native on M1)" and "qemu emulation is only ever best-effort".

Also see the [Known issues for Docker Desktop on Mac with Apple silicon](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/known-issues/).

The solution is to run arm64 containers on Apple silicon machines whenever possible.